# Efficiently iterate over a map for a matching key

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I want to iterate over a java Map and get a case insensitive key match and get a value out.

```
m -> m.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(target).getValue()
```

Is there an efficient way to do the above?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.  If you do not use the `equals` and `hashCode` keying of a map, there is no more efficient way to search a map in the general case than linearly.

If you could guarantee ahead of time that the map only had lowercase keys, and you looked up `target.toLowerCase()`, that would allow you to use the map's efficient `get` function, but it's not clear if that's possible.

Comment: Alternatively you can construct the map as a `new TreeMap(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`